# Deploy application on JBoss 7.1.1 Error 404

Tags: jboss

I deployed a test.war, and logs said no error, and it automatically generated a test.war.deployed at deployment/.
I only have a index.jsp to test, but the browser shows:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /test/
type Status report
message /test/
description The requested resource (/test/) is not available.
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"> </web-app>
```

Here is my jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <jboss-web>
    <context-root>/test</context-root> </jboss-web>
```

What did I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I faced to this problem with my Tapestry 5 application. If your application is tapestry-based, you can find solution here: http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/HowToRunTapestry5OnJBoss7Dot1.